# SQL Server commit and working set

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012

There's a SQL Server instance `MSSQLSERVER` running on local host in windows 7. I realized that its commit is much larger than its working set. Here’s a comparison between my local instance and another instance `MS_MSBI_SSDS` running on Windows Server 2008R2.

*Local SQL Server*

```
Image         PID   Hard Faults/sec  Commit(KB)  Working Set (KB)  Sharable(KB)
sqlservr.exe  2380                0  45 615 948            61 992        17 784
```

*Remote SQL Server*

```
Image         PID   Hard Faults/sec  Commit(KB)  Working Set (KB)  Sharable(KB)  Private(KB)
sqlservr.exe  1964                1   6 464 988         5 496 884        40 608    5 456 636
```

**The large amount of commit makes the local machine almost unusable.** The *commit charge* is at 100% when `MSSQLSERVER` launched. Please notice that there isn’t any particular process running on the local SQL Server. And it has 2 databases (8GB), copied from the remote one.

My questions are

- Why the local instance has a large commit when it has only a small working set?
- Can I find what have been actualy committed ?
- How to decrease its commit charge ?
- Might the problem come from McAfee ? I don't have right to modify it due to company policy. What can I do ? Here's a relative post *[SQLSERVR.EXE High Commit Usage causing a low virtual memory condition](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/403e8bf1-0e72-4c5f-96e5-f07e0311dfc5/sqlservrexe-high-commit-usage-causing-a-low-virtual-memory-condition?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)*.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Commit isn't a measure of actual memory use. It's just memory a process has asked for and the OS has said it will be there when accessed; committed memory may never be accessed and so will never be assigned. True, 45GB is a large number but practically none of it is physically real either in actual RAM or page space given the working set size.

Comment: I understand that the commit isn't a measure of actual memor use. But when _Commit Charge_ reaches 100%, my computer cannot work correctly. Even the web browser, it stops. @simonatrcl

Comment: In SSMS, right-click the server in Object Explorer and go to Properties, Memory tab. What is the min and max memory SQL Server is allowed?

Comment: The local one is [0, 3000] and the remote one is [0, 2147483647] (in MB)